# run.sh - package X does not exist

Tags: java, shell, jar, alfresco, libs

I'm running `./run.sh` from **Alfresco All-in-One** extension but I got the error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:compile
>   (default-compile) on project repo-amp: Compilation failure:
>   Compilation failure:
>
> [ERROR]
>   /home/user/signextension/sign/repo-amp/src/main/java/pt/empt/sign/fields/CreateFields.java:[3,25]
>   package com.itextpdf.text does not exist
>
> [ERROR]
>   /home/user/signextension/sign/repo-amp/src/main/java/pt/empt/sign/fields/CreateFields.java:[4,25]
>   package com.itextpdf.text does not exist
>
> [ERROR]
>   /home/user/signextension/sign/repo-amp/src/main/java/pt/empt/sign/fields/CreateFields.java:[5,1]
>   package com.itextpdf.text.pdf does not exist

My **run.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Downloads the spring-loaded lib if not existing and runs the full all-in-one
# (Alfresco + Share + Solr) using the runner project
springloadedfile=~/.m2/repository/org/springframework/springloaded/1.2.3.RELEASE/springloaded-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar

if [ ! -f $springloadedfile ]; then
mvn validate -Psetup
fi
MAVEN_OPTS="-javaagent:$springloadedfile -noverify -Xms256m -Xmx2G" mvn clean install -Prun
```

I try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Downloads the spring-loaded lib if not existing and runs the full all-in-one
# (Alfresco + Share + Solr) using the runner project
springloadedfile=~/.m2/repository/org/springframework/springloaded/1.2.3.RELEASE/springloaded-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar
itextpdffile=~/.m2/repository/com/itextpdf/itextpdf/5.5.7/itextpdf-5.5.7.jar

if [ ! -f $springloadedfile ] && [ ! -f $itextpdffile ]; then
mvn validate -Psetup
fi
MAVEN_OPTS="-javaagent:$springloadedfile -javaagent:$itextpdffile -noverify -Xms256m -Xmx2G" mvn clean install -Prun
```

But I got the error:

> Failed to find Premain-Class manifest attribute in
>   /home/user/.m2/repository/com/itextpdf/itextpdf/5.5.7/itextpdf-5.5.7.jar
>   Error occurred during initialization of VM agent library failed to
>   init: instrument

Any help for solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The itext library is not a javaagent library, check [this link](http://www.javabeat.net/introduction-to-java-agents/) to learn more about java agents and what are they meant for !

The right way to add itext dependency to your project is by adding this snippet:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.7</version>
</dependency>
```

To your main pom.xml file (or the repo-amp pom.xml alternatively) (in the dependencies section). And of course roll back any changes you made to the run.sh file !

Comment: I've tried this on main pom.xml but does not work. I try now in the repo-amp pom.xml and I think that solved :) Thanks! You know why this not works in the main ?